# Why do these two list Iterators behave differently?

Tags: java, list, iteration

I am  practicing list iteration then I got stuck. My question is, why do these two methods give different results.

The first code prints out a infinite loop. While the second, prints out the next String in the index.

I am new to java, this is also my first language.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    String[] hi = {"yo", "wat", "sup"};
    List<String> l1 = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(hi));

    while (l1.iterator().hasNext()) {


        System.out.println(l1.iterator().next());
        ;
    }
   }
```

## VS

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    String[] hi = {"yo", "wat", "sup"};
    List<String> l1 = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(hi));

    Iterator<String> rator = l1.iterator();

    while (rator.hasNext()) {
      System.out.println(rator.next());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`l1.iterator(` *always* generates a *new* iterator. In the first piece of code you're creating a new iterator, discarding it, recreating it, and discarding it again. Since the iterator doesn't get a chance to reach the end, you'll never exit the loop.

Comment: So basically .iterator is a new iterator every time the while method executes?

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you are creating a new `Iterator` (which starts with the first element again and again) every time you check the condition in the loop.  And then you create more of them in the `println` (2 iterators created per loop).  The program displays the first element (`"yo"`) endlessly.